# How do I configure nginx and ShinobiCCTV?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Link to Shinobi:
https://shinobi.video/

I have a Shinobi which is at 127.0.0.1.
And also the domain `example.com` on `/` is the backend, I want `example.com/shinobi` to host Shinobi.

I tried to do this via nginx, here is my configuration:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /shinobi/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
     }
}
```

This doesn't work for me, I found the answer on reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ShinobiCCTV/comments/fgmce0/problem_with_shinobi_behind_nginx_reverse_proxy/

I changed `baseURL` in `/home/Shinobi/conf.json` to `https://example.com/shinobi/` and restarted Shinobi `pm2 restart all`. I get this response:

```
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [all](ids: [ 0 ])
[PM2] [camera](0) ✓
```

When I go to `https://example.com/shinobi/{TOKEN}/embed/{GROUP}/{CAMERA}/fullscreen%7Cjquery` I get:

```
Cannot GET /shinobi/{TOKEN}/embed/{GROUP}/{CAMERA}/fullscreen%7Cjquery
```

That didn't work for me. Can you please tell me how I can fix this and what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you ever sort this? Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

For me location is /, add the websockets support for Shinobi too, Otherwise you may be able to log in but not able see your video:

proxy_http_version 1.1;

proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

proxy_set_header Host $host;